# axios onUploadProgress + vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to build a small `ProgressBar` component in vue

My parent component is like this :

```
onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
   this.progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total )
   console.log(this.progress)
   }

<ProgressBar :loading="loading" :progress="progress"></ProgressBar>
```

here is my child component:

```
<template>
   <div v-if="loading" class="progress-bar-wrapper">
     <div class="progress-bar" :style="'width:'+progress+'%'">{{progress+'%'}}</div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ProgressBar",
  props: {
    loading: {type:Boolean},
    progress:{type:Number, default:0}
  },
  watch: {
   progress(){
     console.log(this.$props.progress)
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

I narrowed down the issue and it looks like `this.progress` in my parent is not being updated properly; if I put a watcher on it, nothing happens:

```
watch: {
      progress(){
        console.log(this.progress)
      }
    }
```

But if I `console.log(this.progress)` from the callback function I get the expected value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue; as usual with vue you really need to be careful with `this`

here is the working parent component code:

```
let context = this
....
onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
   context.progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have following problem:

`this` is not your vue instance. Did you tried to log `console.log(this)` ? I guess it wont show you your vue instance.

So how to fix it? Well just `.bind()` your vue instance

```
onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
   this.progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total )
   console.log(this.progress)
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: thanks; actually found the same answer and posted it at the same time as your reply

Comment: This answer do not only solve my problem but has really helped me  understand exactly what `bind(this)` is used for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `watch` set `immediate = true`

```
watch: {
  progress: {
    immediate: true, 
    handler (newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(this.progress)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will it log anything on the created hook?

Comment: I mean sorry; I get the first log when it is mounted with value 0 but nothing updates after

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const config = {
    ...
    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
        this.loadPercentage = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
    }
};

axios.post('/url', data, config);
```

**loadPercentage** - in data